# How can I get table records passing table name and column names at runtime in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, dynamic, hibernate-criteria

Requirement is to get the records from database where particular columns and the table name is selected at run time.

I am using Java, Hibernate and Mysql. It is possible using JDBC. but i want to do it using hibernate.

Post the hints, if anybody knows

Thanks in advance

Comment: please try it yourself. SO is for solving problems, not introducing to new fields. Perhaps the documentation is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Hibernate can do much more than just JDBC, what you're looking for can be written like this with Hibernate:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"select s.stock_code from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode")
.setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
List result = query.list();
```

As you can see the table name and columns can be defined on the fly, this is at least on par with JDBC, and probably even simpler. You don't have to use parameters, you can modularly build your query in the code, obviously.

Reference for more details
https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... your help is very precious

Answer (score 0):

`Hibernate` has more features than `JDBC`. The best feauture is `Hibernate` support `Object Oriented Principles`. You can use `Polymorphism`, `Inheritance`, `Encapsulation` for your entities.

You must have a `BaseEntity` class and all other classes must extends from this class.

```
public class BaseEntity {

}
```

Then all other classes extends this class. Assume that, you have two other classes or entities.

User.class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Table(name = "USERS")
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SURNAME")
    private String surname;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String name, String surname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

Info.class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Table(name = "INFO")
@Entity
public class Info extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "TEXT")
    private String text;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    public Info() {
    }

    public Info(String text, int id) {
        this.text = text;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Also you must add `mapping` tag for each class to `configuration.hbm.xml`
Your `DAO` is look like following.

```
public List getList(BaseEntity baseEntity, String[] columnNames) {
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(baseEntity.getClass(), "be");
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    for (String columnName : columnNames) {
        projectionList.add(Projections.property("be." + columnName), columnName); // adding column for selection
    }
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(baseEntity.getClass())); // for mapping result to entity
    return criteria.list();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] columnNames = {"name", "surname"}; // columnNames which you want to select
    List<Info> users = new GeneralDAO().getList(new User(), columnNames); // you can pass any class User, Info or etc.
}
```